# GeoServer as cascading WMTS cache for OS maps API is slow for some requests

Tags: geoserver, wmts

I've configured GeoServer to cascade the OS Maps API wmts service following the excellent article here:

https://blog.ianturton.com/2021/07/22/Cascading-OS-Map-Tiles.html

If I preview the tile layer for this however some initial requests are taking ~4 seconds to complete.

An example request:

http://myserver/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=cite%3ARoad_27700&style=&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A27700&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=EPSG%3A27700%3A7&TileCol=471&TileRow=595

My tile caching settings:

[image]

Are there any obvious reasons why the requests maybe taking this long? Is GeoServer recalculating the tiles? If so, how can this be avoided?

My gridset:

[image]

Comment: Most likely delay is on the network between GeoServer and OS, but it could be reprojecting - depends on your request tiles and the ones you've set up on cascade?

Comment: @IanTurton I've added a bit more detail on my setup. How would I determine if it is reprojecting or just network issues? Networking would seem less likely as it should be coming out of Azure uksouth.

Comment: if you are requesting tiles in something other than 27700 then there will be reprojection other than that it should be fine - speed and Azure buckets is a bit of a black art, but aren't you going over a network from where ever you are and the OS endpoint, or are both those points in uksouth? Might need to turn on debugging to see what's happening and possibly add some code to make timing checks